# Can `throw` be inside a comma subexpression within C++ conditional (ternary) operator?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, conditional-operator, throw

It is well known that `throw` can be placed as the second or the third operand of C++ ternary operator `?:`. But can it be inside a comma subexpression of there operands? It looks like compilers diverge in this regard. Please consider an example:

```
#include <iostream>

void foo(bool b) {
    int i = b ? 1 : (throw 0); //ok everywhere
    if ( !b )
        (std::cout << "smth\n", throw 0); //ok everywhere
    i = b ? 2 : (std::cout << "smth\n", throw 0); //ok in MSVC only
};
```

This example is accepted by MSVC, but rejected by both GCC and Clang, demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/6q46j5exP

Though the error message:

```text
error: third operand to the conditional operator is of type 'void', but the second operand is neither a throw-expression nor of type 'void'
    7 |     i = b ? 2 : (std::cout << "smth\n", throw 0);
      |             ^
```

suggests that it was not rejected intentionally but rather the compiler thinks that the third operand not only has formal type `void` but actually can return.

According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other, it seems that GCC/Clang are right since

> Either E2 or E3 (but not both) is a (possibly parenthesized) throw-expression.

and here we have parenthesized comma expression just finishing with throw-expression.

According to the standard, is MSVC incorrect in accepting the last line of the example?

Comment: fyi and does not explain the difference try `i = b ? 2 : (std::cout << "smth\n", throw 0, 42);`  this makes the types of the sub-expressions (E2 and E3) the same.

Comment: @RichardCritten, thanks for the idea. This is indeed accepted by all: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/85YGz9ffG

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Clang and GCC are correct to reject it. It's pretty straightforward:

> **[expr.cond]**
>
> [2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.cond#2) If either the second or the third operand has type `void`, one of the following shall hold:
>
> - The second or the third operand (but not both) is a (possibly parenthesized) *[throw-expression](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.throw#nt:throw-expression)* ([[expr.throw]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.throw)); the result is of the type and value category of the other. The *[conditional-expression](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.cond#nt:conditional-expression)* is a bit-field if that operand is a bit-field.
> - Both the second and the third operands have type `void`; the result is of type `void` and is a prvalue.

The wording is pretty precise here. It says one operand **is a** throw-expression when the first bullet applies. And `(std::cout << "smth\n", throw 0)` **is not** a throw-expression. It's parenthesized comma expression.

So we can only be in the case of the second bullet, but its conditions don't hold either. So a "shall" requirement is broken, and the program is thus ill-formed.

Now, MSVC may be offering an extension around this, but it's not standard.

Answer (score 8):

As noted by [@StoryTeller - Unslander Monica](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68781810/147192), there is a specification restriction with operands evaluating to `void`.

I should note, however, that in this case the restriction is trivially bypassed:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

void foo(bool b) {
    int i = b ? 1 : (throw 0); //ok everywhere
    if ( !b )
        (std::cout << "smth\n", throw 0);

    //  OR

    i = b ? 2 : throw ((std::cout << "smth\n"), 0);

    //  OR

    i = b ? 2 : (std::cout << "smth\n", throw 0, 2);
                                            // ^^^ extra addition
}
```

The extra `, 2` changes the type of `(std::cout << "smth\n", throw 0, 2)` to `int`, at which point the quoted rule no longer applies -- the operand is no longer of type `void` -- and therefore there is no longer any restriction on the operand.

*(And now we can question what is the point of the restriction in the standard...)*

Comment: YMMV, but I think that `throw((std::cout << "smth\n"), 0)` makes it more visibly obvious that the expression ends up throwing an exception. (Though `if (! b) { std::cout << "smth\n"; throw 0; } int i = 2;` is probably clearest.)

Comment: @ruakh: Indeed, may be better. I'll list both alternatives.